# How does one respond with a redirect from using $httpBackend.whenGET in angular-mock?

Tags: angularjs, angular-mock

I would like to mimic a redirect that would otherwise be handled by our server using Angular's MockService $httpBackend.whenGET() method.

In short, here is what I have --->

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/foo\/moo\/redirect\/.*$/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
   return [308, 'http://iwanttosendyouhere.com', {}];
});
```

I am not finding any solid examples for how to deal with redirects using this service and thought to ask the hive if anyone had already accomplished this before I start scraping the source.